# Why do I not need "std::" in some scenarios?

Tags: c++, vector, namespaces

Why does this work:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> nums = {3, 7, 5};
  std::cout << *min_element(nums.begin(), nums.end()) << "\n";
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int nums[] = {3, 7, 5};
  std::cout << *min_element(nums, nums + 3) << "\n";
}
```

I've discovered that if I change the call to `min_element` in the second example so it includes a namespace like `std::min_element`, it works fine. What I don't understand is why this isn't necessary in the first example. Does the `vector` somehow magically know where to find `min_element`, and if so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is employed and `min_element` is found. In this example, the arguments to `min_element` are iterators (`nums.begin(), nums.end()`).

> Argument-dependent lookup, also known as ADL, or Koenig lookup, is the set of rules for looking up the unqualified function names in function-call expressions, including implicit function calls to overloaded operators. **These function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments** in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.

In the implementation you are using, the iterators `begin()` and `end()` of the `vector` are implemented in such a way that this could be possible.

In the second example, this is not possible because the arguments to `min_element` are just **addresses** of the array `nums`. So you have to specifically use `std::` so that the lookup will be qualified.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on implementation? i.e. How the iterator type is defined for `std::vector`.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Are there implementations where an iterator is implemented in a way that `begin()` and `end()` just return `T*`?

Comment: @songyuanyao: Based on your observation, I have qualified the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think at least the standard doesn't require it must be a class type.

Comment: Would it be considered best practice to just write `std::` anyways in all scenarios? I mean, how can you ever know that leaving it off will work without just trying it and seeing what happens?

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin: It is always better to write `std::` to clearly say that you want to use this particular function from `std`. Otherwise, there is a danger that a function with the same name from some other namespace can be called.

Comment: I would either do a `using std::min_element;` (in the \*.cpp source file only, not in a \*.h header) or qualify it with a `std::min_element` (\*.cpp or \*.h).  What I recommend against doing is `using namespace std;` (bad everywhere: \*.\*).